# MySQL: regex to match variations of a word, but not one variation?

Tags: mysql, regex

MySQL: I'm trying to match a word ('anchor') and most variations of that word ('anchorman'/'anchorwoman', 'anchor man'/'anchor woman', 'co-anchor', 'anchored', etc), but I want to exclude 'anchorage' specifically. Is there a way to do this?

I wrote:
`table.column regexp '[[:<:]]anchor[^age]'`

Words I want to include are:

`anchor
co-anchor
anchored
anchorman
anchor man
anchorwoman
anchor woman
anchoring`

but not `anchorage`

The problem with the query is that it's taking out `anchored`.

Comment: Whats wrong with using `where column like '%anchor%' and column != 'anchorage'`?

Comment: The POSIX engine isn't powerful enough to do it with one regex. Otherwise the answer would have been to use a negative lookahead: `anchor(?!age)`

Comment: @sgeddes that works! I was trying to generalize, but at the same time I guess I wasn't. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about not using a regular expression at all?

```
where replace(column, 'anchorage', '') like '%anchor%'
```

Of course, you can still use a regular expression to check for word boundaries.  But removing the word you don't want seems like an easy solution for your specific question.

Answer (score 0):

The general case of this task is called "stemming" and it's notoriously difficult.

But, let's answer your specific question:

```
  column REGEXP '[[:<:]](co-)?anchor(|man|woman|ed|ing)[[:>:]]'
```

should meet your needs.  An explanation:

```
[[:<:]]     beginning of word
(co-)?      optional "co-" prefix
anchor      the root of the word you want to recognize
(|man|woman|ed|ing)  several alternative suffixes. The first alternative is empty.
[[:>:]]     end of word.
```

Notice this will match "anchor man", "anchor woman" and "anchor goose".

Notice your example contains `[^age]`.  This means "any single character other than a,g, or e. Not exactly what you want.

Comment: Should I use ?(|man|woman|ed|ing) in case the word is just 'anchor'?

Comment: also, ```regexp '[[:<:]]anchor(man|woman|ed|ing)?[[:>:]]'``` turned out to match the query better.